# Set MongoDB collection in spring boot application.properties

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, configuration

I have several collections that share the following same simple schema:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f35293fe4b09cef5df64721"
    },
    "dui": ["258705008", "112234008", ...],
    "ID": "ABCD"
}
```

Now, I specify the access the collection with Spring boot '@Document(collection = "XYZ")' annotation. Therefore, I must specify my collection in the '@Document' annotation itself. However, I would prefer to have all configurations within my SpringBoot configuration files.

So, the question is, is there a way to configure 'XYZ' through the application.properties file? Or what else mechanism could be used to bind a specific collection through the SpringBoot configuration files?

Many thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue through a SpEL Expression. I used them as follows:
@Document(collection = "#{@bean.getNameXYZ()}")

All the best